# need clarification on how the kuberentes deployment yaml works for role creation

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

Below mentioned yaml file snippet is used for a role creation :
I am new in kubernetes and so looking for a reference link to elaborate the rules mentioned in the yaml . For example , my understanding is “” indicates core API groups of kubernetes and then my question is what is “extensions” for … Similarly for rest of the yaml looking for a reference / explanation. Thanks a lot guys for the help

```
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
- apiGroups: ["batch"]
  resources:
  - jobs
  - cronjobs
  verbs: ["*"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a way of grouping k8s objects. As objects get added to k8s, they are added in a specific group.

`core API group` is **v1**, so every time you see `apiVersion: v1`, such as **Pod** object, it is `core API group`. `replicaSet`, `Service` `ConfigMap`, `Node`, `secrets`, etc. are **v1** too. These are the main object k8s works with, that have been almost from the very beginning, and are solid (In my own words).

Objects can be moved from one group to another depending on their maturity. `Deployments`, for example, are now in `apps/v1` group, but they used to be in `extensions/v1beta1`. I, personally, have `yaml` files with the old group, that when I try to create, I get an error from the server. I think there was a period, when both `apps/v1` and `extentions/v1beta1` were valid. Not sure about this though.

K8s is an extensible platform, so you can also create your own objects through `CustomResourceDefinition`, and put them in a custom groups. This is the case of **Ingress Controllers**, **Meshes**, etc. Istio, for example creates bunch of objects, such as `Gateway`, `VirtualService`, `DestinationRule`, etc. Once you create this CDRs, you can get them with a normal `kubectl get gateway`, for example.

`batch/v1` is for **Jobs**. I think there are no more objects in `batch/v1`. **CronJobs** are `batch/v1beta1`.

HorizontalPodAutoscaler is in `autoscaling/v1`.

Now, you don't really need to know these objects and their groups by heart. As the other answer says, you can always do `kubectl explain OBJECT` to know to which groups belongs an object. So a normal workflow for creating RBAC rules would be:

1. What object do I want to manipulate the access control? -> Say jobs
2. `kubectl explain jobs` -> And from here I will get that jobs are
   batch/v1
3. I will create an RBAC rule for `batch`.

The verbs are self explanatory.

Note that the group is only the first part; `batch`, `extensions`, "" (as v1 has nothing), etc.

There is more information about RBAC (like nonResourceURLs, for the paths that exposes api-server), but I think this should be enough to make a picture of how apiGroups work. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl  explain clusterrole.rules` will provide the detail explanation.

```
FIELDS:
   apiGroups    <[]string> -required-
     APIGroups is the name of the APIGroup that contains the resources. If this
     field is empty, then both kubernetes and origin API groups are assumed.
     That means that if an action is requested against one of the enumerated
     resources in either the kubernetes or the origin API group, the request
     will be allowed
```

**Extensions** is  deprecated apiGroup, where unorganized resources used to live   , currently, resources are moving to specific group. for instance DaemonSet, Deployment, StatefulSet, and ReplicaSet will migrate to **apps** group.[api-deprecations-in-1-16/](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/)

here is the naming convention

> The named groups are at REST path /apis/$GROUP_NAME/$VERSION, and use `apiVersion: $GROUP_NAME/$VERSION` (e.g. apiVersion: batch/v1).
>
> The core group, often referred to as the legacy group, is at the REST path /api/v1 and uses `apiVersion: v1.`

Full list of supported API groups can be seen in [Kubernetes API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/).

**Batch** is another group in k8s which consist cronjob and job resources.

**Verb** these are  actions  such as list, get, etc [Verb-on-resources](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#verbs-on-resources)

you can list all of the resources and their group with the following command
`kubectl api-resources`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Yes , i did check that .As I understand, for - apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"] , "" indicates core API groups of kubernetes .similarly what does it signify by mentioning "extensions" and  "apps" .
resources: ["*"] - Does it indicate full access to all the resources ?
Similarly looking for explanation for verbs: ["*"]
- apiGroups: ["batch"] and rest of the snippet